# MySQL query from 2 tables, get value of ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to search without success what I need for my problem, so let me explain it.

I have 2 tables, let's say client and state

On the client table I have this columns:

idClient,
   name,
   idState

On the state table I have this columns:

idState,
   name

What I'm trying to do is a query on MySQL, to get the client info, but at the same time, on the result get the name of the state of the client and not the ID of it.

How can I do this?

Thanks and sorry if its all rdy answer on some place else (could not find the answer for this)

Comment: Yep, on phpMyAdmin on SQL query trying this, i though its simple but never done join on query, just "simple" ones

Comment: See this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thanks fir the tuturial, if needed to be more complex, I will learn from it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do with an inner join

```
 select client.idClient, client.name,  state.name
 from client 
 inner join state on client.idState = state.idState
```